# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n}/(n+1)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt n}{n+1}$$

Comment: I would be really thankful if someone help me

Comment: $$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n-1}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{1-\frac{1}{n}}\stackrel{n\to \infty}\to \frac{0}{1-0}=0$$

Comment: Okay Thanks! But how did you do that with 1 div by squr(n)?

Comment: I divided the numerator and the denominator by $n$. We have $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Aaaaa ! I get it. But is there a simple wa.y

Comment: Notice $\sqrt{n}=n^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple case of an indeterminate form, more specifically, $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ Using L'Hopital's's rule, differentiate the numerator and denominator

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dn}\sqrt n}{\frac{d}{dn}n+1} = lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2}n^\frac{-1}{2}}{1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2*\sqrt n}=0$$

Comment: Yeah i am terribly sorry .. Didn't see the sign ...

Comment: I haven't done nothing

Answer (score 2):

In general, when faced with the INFINITE limit of a quotient, divide by the highest power of n. For example: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3x^2 + 2x + 1}{2x^2 + 1}
= \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3 + \frac{2}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}}{2 + \frac{1}{x^2}}
= \frac{3}{2}$$
This question is the same, and provides a very easy way to get a lot of limits.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for positive $n$,
$$0 < \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1} < \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
As
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = 0,$$ 
we can use the squeeze theorem to conclude that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1} = 0$$